# mongoid-paperclip: Photo is not recognized by the 'identify' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, unicorn

I'm migrating from *Active Record* to *Mongoid*, and this paperclip stuff used to work fine. I'm using *Ubuntu 12.04*.

I've got this code in my mongoid document:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :thumb => "60x60",
    :small => "100x100",
    :medium => "300x200",
    :large => "600x400"
  },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "#{Rails.env}/merc:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :url => ":s3_alias_url",
  :bucket => '%^&*&^'
```

I have the *rmagick* gem installed and the `command_path` pointing to where the various imagemagick commands are -> '/usr/bin'.

I'm using *Unicorn* as my webserver, and I have verified that identiy and convert are available by putting this in my view:

```
<%= `which convert` %>
<%= `echo $PATH` %>
```

But alas, when I try to upload the image I get :

```
Photo /tmp/qdoba20121005-27609-1m3kq9c.jpg is not recognized by the
'identify' command.  Photo /tmp/qdoba20121005-27609-1m3kq9c.jpg is not
recognized by the 'identify' command.  Photo
/tmp/qdoba20121005-27609-1m3kq9c.jpg is not recognized by the
'identify' command.   Photo /tmp/qdoba20121005-27609-1m3kq9c.jpg is
not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

Seemingly one for every one of the styles I have defined.

I've confirmed that the file exists, and I can run identify on the file from the commandline.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recent update to the Cocaine gem that is breaking the imagemagick filenames for a lot of people - check it out because rolling back Cocaine to the previous version may help.

See here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038

Comment: Thats exactly right! Adding gem 'cocaine','0.3.2' fixed the issue.

Comment: Good call, I recently upgraded all my gems and ran into the same issue.